# Post JSON data to server and parse the response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I need to POST the JSON format data to the server URL. The server will send the response in same JSON format. I need to parse it and get the data. How to do it? please help me with an example.

Comment: What server platform you are using (ASP, PHP, etc)? Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev i am using PHP

Answer (score 0):

at client side (to convert into the json)--->

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
```

& at server side to get the actual data--->

```
var dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJSONText);
```

php--->

```
<?php
$jsonTxt = '{"abc":1111,"xyz":222}';

var_dump(json_decode($jsonTxt));
var_dump(json_decode($jsonTxt, true));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse()` which may be supported in most browsers.

```
var response = {"success":true, "data":"My data"};

var json_res = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(json_res.data)
```

Alternatively, if you are using some javascript library, for example jQuery you may have an helper. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this.

```
     var data = $(":input").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
```

On Server side :

```
public static function createFromJson( $jsonString )
    {
        $object = json_decode( $jsonString );
        return new self( $object->firstName, $object->lastName );
    }
```